# Help in using Teraterm

Tags: microcontroller, uart, serial, microprocessor, proteus

Greetings electrical engineers, I am an undergraduate electrical engineering student. I was trying to configure Teraterm so that I can use it simultaneously with Proteus for serial communication with Atmega16 but i cannot select the serial mode
[image]

Comment: Tera Term grays out the Serial option if there are no available serial ports. Usually, you cannot use serial ports from more than one application at once. If it is used in Proteus, close it there and it might be usable in Tera Term.

Comment: There are no available serial ports to open. It is unclear what you want to achieve and how you want to achieve it. How do you expect Teraterm to work with Proteus?

Comment: You can use virtual serial null modems and hubs to create all kinds of crossbars and watchers for serial interfaces. See for example [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Either there is a fault with the Teraterm installation, or there are no serial ports available.

You can't share one serial port between 2 applications; if the port is in use by one application, no others can use it.

There are PC utilities you can run that allow a port to be shared, just search for 'serial port sharing'. Alternatively you can can add a second USB port to the PC and create a simple 'Y' cable, so the data from the ATMega goes to the two receive data lines on the PC.